# Synchronizing server side and client side rendering

Tags: websocket, client-server, rendering, webgl

I have an applications that is composed of a server side rendering component and a client side rendering component. The server side generates the image, sends it to the client where is is rendered using WebGL textures. The client also renders a bounding box around the image. Whenever the user moves the mouse, an model-view matrix is computed and sent to the server via a websocket interface. The client must then wait for the server to generate and send the image back.

The issue is that the orientation of bounding box I am drawing seems to get several frames ahead of the orientation of the image that is rendered on the server. I do not update the modelview transform that is sent to the server until after I render the image that is returned from the server. This is really perplexing. Anybody have any ideas on how this could occur?